# How to derive the equation of a line going through a set of coordinates then give the next coordinate in the sequence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, functions

How to derive the equation/function generating a set of coordinates and determine the next coordinate?
[image]

Comment: Despite your question title, this data doesn't form a line.

Comment: I appologize.  Due to my lack of knowledge i called it a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
15 & = 3 \times 5\\
165 & = 3 \times 5 \times 11\\
2805 & = 3 \times 5 \times 11 \times 17\\
81345 & = 3 \times 5 \times 11 \times 17 \times 29\\ 
4445145 & = 3 \times 5 \times 11 \times 17 \times 29 \times 41
\end{align}
Hence, what you have seems to be the following
$$a_n = p_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \times \cdots \times p_n \times p_{n+1}$$
where $p_k$ is the minimum of the $k^{th}$ pair of twin prime.

**EDIT**

[OEIS supports this claim.](http://oeis.org/A097489)

Comment: This is very good information and the website linked is very useful.